# which code I should put into a partal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml, partial-views

Ideally the code which is reusable, that we can put into a septate partial and can call it from different actions.

Now, if my parial `_list.html.haml` file has code

```
 #betting_list
   %table.table
    %tr  
    %th{:align => "left"}="Start time"
    %th{:align => "left"}="Fixture"
    %th{:align => "left"}="Won"
    %th{:align => "left"}="Draw"
    %th{:align => "left"}="Lost"
    %th{:align => "left"}="Amount"
  - @upcoming_event.each do |event|
    %tr{:class => cycle('even', 'odd')}
      %td=event.start_at.strftime("%b %d %H:%M")
      %td=link_to event.name, event
      - event.outcomes.each do |outcome|
        - if outcome.label =="Won"
          %td=outcome.odds 
        - if outcome.label =="Draw"
          %td=outcome.odds 
        - if outcome.label =="Lost"
          %td=outcome.odds 
      %td=event.bets.count
= paginate(@upcoming_event)
```

**Should we always keep a  a data row or loop in different partial or ?**. I am in delimma. I don't need to re-use that loop part to reuse.

Is is possible to refactor such code ?

Comment: I don;t get your `if outcome.label ==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the looping better in a new partial.

Also I see the multiple IF's, a bit confusing.

You can do this

```
- if (["Won","Lost","Draw"].include? outcome.label)
    %td=outcome.odds
```

Answer (score 1):

As for different partials, it all depends on reuse or readability.  A properly named partial could also help explain what's going on for maintenance reasons especially if there are no comments.

Case statement makes it a little more readable.  But that's just an opinion.

```
case outcome.label
when "Won", "Lost", "Draw"
  %td=outcome.odds
end
```